# Nginx remove exposing port 80/tcp on a docker container, leave only 8080

Tags: docker, nginx, port

I have set a Nginx to listen on a port `8080` in `files/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` by adding `listen 8080;` to the only one server block I have.

I run Nginx by docker run with `-p 8080:8080`

I would like to ask why there is `80/tcp` under PORTS of `docker ps` command as below?

```
STATUS         NAMES               IMAGE                       PORTS
Up 6 minutes   docker-nginx        docker-nginx:1.17.8         80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
```

command `docker inspect docker-nginx` shows:

```
 "HostConfig": {
        "PortBindings": {
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
          

"Config": {
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "80/tcp": {},
            "8080/tcp": {}
        },

    "NetworkSettings": {
        (...)
        "Ports": {
            "80/tcp": null,
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },
```

My intention is to have Nginx listen only to `8080` and not be accessible under any other port even by other containers belonging to the same network as Nginx. How to make Nginx not exposing the `80/tcp` port?

I'm using a build that is FROM an official `nginx:1.17.8` image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dockerfile for the Nginx image should have the `expose` instruction for port 80. On the Nginx website, you should be able to find the dockerfile for the image you are using, and should have the `expose 80` command.

If you do not want the port 80 exposed, even though it will not be used if you are using port 8080, then remove or comment out `expose 80` in the Dockerfile and then build the image.

Comment: When building `FROM nginx:alpine`, for example, isn't `EXPOSE 3000` should override it?